# IntelliJ + Spring: how to enable table names checking in HQL queries?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.2 and both Hibernate and JPA in my project. I use IntelliJ Community 2016.2.4, same as my colleague. The difference is that when he types something in HQL (i.e. @Query("SELECT id FROM usesrs)) it automatically checks the table names against the real DB structure - there is no "usesrs" table, but there is a "user" table. So his project doesn't compile unless he corrects it - what a wonderful feature! Sometimes it takes me a lot of time to spot such bugs...

Can you tell me how can I enable this in IntelliJ? What I tried:

1) When I go to `Preferences / Editor / Language injections / "+" sign / Java Parameter` I don't see SQL on the list, not speaking about HQL (but JQL is there which is crazy...). Anyway looks like I want to enable something deeper than just plain syntax check, it has to check against the database structure.

2) When I go to `File / Project structure / Facets / "+" sign` I don't see JPA there, just some Android options and Java-Gradle.

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three conclusions on this topic:

1) As @Liping Huang pointed out, the live checks (and I imagine mistakes highligting) is only in Ultimate edition

2) I investigated the issue more deeply and looks like I actually **have** some basic support for this, but I just omitted the error message hidden lower in the stack. In the Community I have to try to run the app, so no live highlighting. Then, if there is an error in the table name, the message will be in the stack trace.

Here is the example, notice the "Usesrs is not mapped" message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'protectedController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepositoryImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract void com.ekinnolab.database.repository.user.userRepository.setAsDeletedById(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:592) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
(…)

//    cutting out 150 about lines
(...)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        ... 69 common frames omitted
 HERE ==> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Usesrs is not mapped
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3687) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3576) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:716) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.updateStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:373) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
            ... 77 common frames omitted
```

3) BTW, for pure SQL there are some interesting plugins out there. Just go to `IntelliJ IDEA / Preferences / Plugins / Browse repositories`. "SQL Query Plugin" is one of those looking promising.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunate JPA/Hibernate features are supported in the Ultimate version.

[image]

IDEA has the **Language Injections** which can inject a language (such as SQL, RegExp, XML, HTML, CSS, etc.) into a string literal in your code and, as a result, get comprehensive coding assistance when editing that literal.

You can get a help [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/using-language-injections.html) and a tip here to [Using language injections in SQL](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/using-language-injections-in-sql.html)

Answer (score 1):

In the Database view is your datasource setup?

If it's not already visible go to view -> Tool Windows -> Database

There you should see a data source for your connection.

If it is not there you'll need to set it up using + -> "Data Source" then select the DB that your using and set up your connection.

Once this is done OR if the DB Connection is already present you'll want to synchronize the datasource using the "Refresh" looking icon in the Database view.

Then click on more schemas and pick the schema your using and hit Synchronize on that as well. Intellij should now know about the DB and your table structures.

Hopefully it can then check your queries automatically unless there is something else amiss.

Comment: hi, I don't see such a "Database" position in under "Tool windows". Maybe it's ultimate version only

Comment: My mistake, I thought I was using community when i checked that, but I was looking at ultimate. See the answer @Liping posted. I would double check that your colleague doesn't have the Ultimate Edition of Intellij.